# Linking project window with editor in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Is it possible to link project window/bar with editor? In eclipse there is button in project window called "link with editor". I would like to have exactly the same thing in PhpStorm.

**Explanation:**
Current active file opened in editor is automatically highlighted in project tree. If I change active file in editor to another, without even touching project window, it should change highlighted file as well. It should also keep current active file highlighted all the time if possible.

I didn't found such option in PhpStorm. If there is no such thing in PhpStorm, maybe there is plugin for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just enable **"Autoscroll from Source"** in **Project View** side panel options (under "cog" icon or via right click on panel header/title)

[image]